# jQuery 1.8, async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated

Tags: jquery

I have been having a few issues with ajax error function getting called while the script is taking a while to load. But I was able to fix it by adding `async: false`.

E.g:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: REQUEST_URL,
    async: false,
    data: {
        'id': id
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(output) { 
        // success
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error, please refresh the page');
    }
});
```

When reading the docs it says:

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR
>   ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the complete/success/error
>   callbacks.

**Q)** What does the last part mean about jqXHR ($.Deferred)? Does this effect my script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not affect your script.

It means that, when performing synchronous AJAX requests, one should not use the [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) API exposed by the object returned by `$.ajax()` (like [done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) or [fail()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) for instance), but rely on the `complete` and `error` handlers instead.

In other words, your code already uses the right pattern. You would have to modify it if it used deferred operations like:

```
// Do not write this code.
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: REQUEST_URL,
    async: false,           // <-- Synchronous request.
    data: {
        'id': id
    },
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(output) {  // <-- Use of deferred method.
    // success
}).fail(function() {        // <-- There also.
    alert('Error, please refresh the page');
});
```

Comment: thanks, just wanted to make sure my code wouldn't break in future jquery